# how to get value of html textarea in string variable using c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a master page and one content page.
In content page i have a textarea for get value from user.
i don't want to make it asp control using add runat = server.
without adding runat server i want to get value of textarea in a string variable which is defined in code behind file of my page using c#

In short i want to get value of Html control in code behind file using c#

Comment: in short it cannot be done without adding runat=server

Comment: @RPM1984 - Unless you use Swanny's solution. ;)

Comment: Well, of course you can access a field via the POST, but i got the impression he was trying to access it on some other event (ie Page Load).

Answer (score 1):

Give the TextArea element a name attribute and then you can access it via the Request.Form["*name*"] collection if your using POST or Request.QueryString["*name*"] if GET. You probably should use the IsPostBack property of the page to ensure it has been sent. Are you encountering an issue?